Bound for a "reverse triangle inequality" on matrices
For $A$ and $B$ being two $n \times n$ matrices and $||\cdot||$ the operator norm, I was tasked with finding a counter-example to the claim that $|| |A| - |B| || \leq ||A-B||$, where $|A| = \sqrt{A^*A}$ is the absolute value of $A$. I was able to find a counter example, but there was less than a 5 percent difference between the operator norms.
This leads me to the following question: what is the (or does there exist a) constant $C$ such that $|| |A| - |B| || \leq C||A-B||$?
I was able to find the article "An Inequality for Hilbert-Schmidt Norm" by Araki and Yamagami that showed that $|| |A| - |B| ||_F \leq \sqrt 2||A-B||_F$ for $||\cdot||_F$ the Frobenius norm, which seems it should say something about the operator norms, but I'm not exactly sure what. I would also be interested to know if the constant depended on the dimension, or if it was different in infinite dimensions a la a Hilbert space.

Every norm on a finite dimensional vector space is equivalent (in the sense of norms). As the space of $n \times n$ matrices is finite-dimensional, the inequality that you found immediately implies that there exists such a constant $C$ for the desired inequality (with the operator norms).
To find an exact value for $C$, you can think about establishing the constants that show the operator norm and frobenius norm are equivalent.
